# Отличие торговца от продавца

Tags: лексика

Какая существует разница между торговцем и продавцом? Верно ли, что продавец — это лицо, отпускающее товар, а торговец — лицо, занимающееся организацией продажи (производством, закупкой товара, наймом работников и т. д.)?

Answer (score 3):

Придется ответить, хотя я и голосовал за закрытие.

Продавец - это сторона сделки купли-продажи. Вторая сторона - покупатель.
Торговец - синоним купца (не совсем, правда, точный), то есть профессия или род занятий: осуществление торговли, обычно каким-то конкретным товаром. Происхождение товара может быть различно.

Это ключевое. Остальная разница - субъективна, наворотить можно чего угодно.

(+)

Не поместился у меня ответ в комментарии.

@РиммаМихайлова

> А источник можете привести? Хотя тут и без источника видно, что вы
> субъективны. В словаре синонимов : продавец — торговец

Естественно, я субъективен, тут просто невозможно дать объективный ответ. Почему я и голосовал за закрытие. Но скажите мне, пожалуйста, кто автор словаря, на который вы с таким энтузиазмом ссылаетесь? Мало того, что словари синонимов вообще не самый лучший источник для установления семантических различий, так еще и сам подбор синонимов впечатляет оригинальностью. У Абрамова во всяком случае ничего даже отдаленно похожего нет:

> *Торговец, торгаш, лавочник, купец (купчик, купчина), промышленник, барышник, скупщик, перекупщик, коммерсант, негоциант.*

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%86&all=x.

Всё. "Продавца" там нет вовсе.

Что до источников, мне казалось, что я говорю вещи самоочевидные. Ну, коли так, возьмите любой ТОЛКОВЫЙ словарь.

> ТОРГОВЕЦ, -вца; м. Тот, кто занимается частной торговлей. Т. рыбой,
> пушниной. Т. яблоками. Т. с лотка. Частный т.
> (БТС Кузнецов)

Не лучшим образом сформулировано, плеоназм напоминает, но все же вполне в духе того, что я сказал.

И соответственно:

> ПРОДАВЕЦ, -вца; м. 1. Работник магазина, лавки, отпускающий товар
> покупателям. П. универмага. П. кооперативного киоска. П. в книжном
> магазине. 2. Тот, кто продаёт что-л. П. цветов. П. на рынке, на
> базаре.

Там же.

(++)

Еще.
Я разобрался. По вашей ссылке нечто, напоминающее более "помощник кроссвордиста", чем словарь синонимов. Первоисточник - https://synonymonline.ru/

Создаются такие шедевры так. Берется большой корпус текстов (сейчас это не сложно) и програмно надергиваются все слова, как-то связанные с гнездом. Потом немного причесывается, но вычесать все, естественно, невозможно. Отсюда и эти  *воистину шедевральные находки синонимических пар **"продавец"-"сиделец" и "продавец"-"целовальник"***.  Пожалуйста, проверяйте источники, на которые ссылаетесь, хотя бы на здравый смысл.

Comment: _А источник можете привести? Хотя тут и без источника видно, что вы субъективны._ В словаре синонимов : продавец — торговец (http://endic.ru/synonym/Prodavec-198584.html).

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова дополнил ответ.

Comment: Так и Вы проверяйте значения слов, прежде чем наехать и отчесать. Чем же Вам не понравились *целовальник* и *сиделец*? Целовальник — Устар. *Продавец* вина в питейном заведении, кабаке. (https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) Сиделец — Устар. Приказчик, *продавец* в лавке, а также *продавец* за стойкой в кабаке, трактире. (https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%86)

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Тем, что это устаревшие значения.  И синонимами в обычном смысле не являются. А если на то пошло, прошу дать ссылку на авторитетный и проверяемый источник того, что "торговец" является синонимом "продавец". Если дадите, разберемся, кто на кого наехал.

Comment: Интересно-интересно! 1. Вы цитируете мои слова, а ведь они — Ваши (*А источник можете привести? Хотя тут и без источника видно, что вы субъективны*). 2. Почему же Вы имеете право на субъективность, а другой участник — нет? 3. Чем же "Ваш" словарь синонимов Абрамова лучше словаря Тришина? *Негоциант* — Устар. Лицо, ведшее оптовую торговлю, преимущественно за пределами своей страны. *Лавочник* — Устар. Владелец лавки или продавец в лавке. *Барышник* — Устар. Тот, кто занимается перепродажей ради барыша; перекупщик. P. S. Здесь (в уважаемом Вами словаре) устаревшие значения Вам нравятся.

Comment: 1. Я не имел в виду цитирование. 2. Здрасьте... это то же мои слова? 3.  Вы только сейчас дали наводку на Тришина. Буду разбираться колт так. Ну для начала тем, что Абрамов есть на грамоте, а Тришина в Инете нет.

Comment: А, нашел. Ну сейчас буду смотреть. http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/synonyms-trishin/index.htm

Comment: Ой, нет. Я не могу это серьезно воспринять. Продавец - мясник? Селедочник? Впариватель-втюхиватель? Но даже у него нету вашей пары "продавец"-"торговец".

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос довольно интересный, т.к. семантические различия между эти словами далеко не очевидны.

В целом наиболее точно ответил *behemothus*. Торговец характеризует род деятельности человека, сферу его занятий. Продавец чаще всего это роль либо в транзакции купли-продажи, либо в конкретном событийном контексте (продавец в магазине). Также продавец может характеризовать род деятельности (продавец обуви, продавец-консультант), но сочетаемостные свойства в этой роли будут отличаться от *торговца*.

Для лучшего понимания различий, сравните сочетаемость обоих слов:

- [Сочетаемость слова «торговец»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%86)
- [Сочетаемость слова «продавец»](https://kartaslov.ru/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%86)

*П.С.* Могу также предположить, что семантика этих двух слов будет меняться и дальше, оставляя за словом *торговец* в основном книжную сферу применения. Это связано с тем, что для окружающего нас мира стала менее характерна роль торговца монотоваром (*торговец обувью*, *торговец тканями*); торговлей стали чаще заниматься организации, и для отображения роли в оргструктуре слово *продавец* более характерно.

Со временем частота употреблений слова *продавец* возрастёт настолько, что оно начнёт "выдавливать" слово *торговец* из речи, даже в более характерных для него контекстах. И естественным образом произойдёт "окнижнивание" *торговца*, а в разговорной речи будет в основном употребляться *продавец*. Это перераспределение можно видеть уже сейчас.

Answer (score -1):

Продавец это тот, кто продаёт, а торговец - это тот, кто выгодно (дёшево) покупает, чтобы выгодно (дороже) продать товар. Для более успешного осуществления этого процесса торговец работает и над вопросами организации, процедур закупок и транспортировок товара, разных юридических проволочек и нюансов.

Comment: А источник можете привести? Хотя тут и без источника видно, что вы субъективны. Тот кто покупает исключительно с целью перепродажи - это спекулянт.

Comment: @behemothus Думаю, что слово "коммерсант" более точно отражает современное отношение к торговой спекуляции.

Comment: @grizzly *слово "коммерсант" более точно отражает современное отношение к торговой спекуляции* - ээээ... Спорно.Коммерция - это, грубо говоря, торговля товаром **материальным**. А спекуляции, к примеру, на биржах под эту категорию не очень-то подпадают. Впрочем, я в ответе своем уже сказал, что вопрос этот предельно субъективен. А вне контекста - еще и умозрителен. Если продолжать обсуждение в этом направлении, мы впоремся в такую непролазную политэкономию (с философией в придачу), что получим  очередного сферического коня в вакууме.